Have x86_64 version r but openssl package complies to arm64
I am using R on a M1 MacOS 13.5. I installed my R from CRAN years ago. This is the version:
R version 4.2.3 (2023-03-15) -- "Shortstop Beagle"
Copyright (C) 2023 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)

Back then some packages did not have an ARM64 version. So I installed the x86_64 version of R. Then I installed my packages and things worked fine until today when I started a new renv environment. I tried to install devtools but openssl failed to install. This is the error message:
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘openssl’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object '/Users/myname/R Projects/grnAnalysis/renv/library/R-4.2/x86_64-apple-darwin17.0/00LOCK-openssl/00new/openssl/libs/openssl.so':
  dlopen(/Users/myname/R Projects/grnAnalysis/renv/library/R-4.2/x86_64-apple-darwin17.0/00LOCK-openssl/00new/openssl/libs/openssl.so, 0x0006): tried: '/Users/myname/R Projects/grnAnalysis/renv/library/R-4.2/x86_64-apple-darwin17.0/00LOCK-openssl/00new/openssl/libs/openssl.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64')), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/Users/myname/R Projects/grnAnalysis/renv/library/R-4.2/x86_64-apple-darwin17.0/00LOCK-openssl/00new/openssl/libs/openssl.so' (no such file), '/Users/myname/R Projects/grnAnalysis/renv/library/R-4.2/x86_64-apple-darwin17.0/00LOCK-openssl/00new/openssl/libs/openssl.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64'))

Am I understanding it correctly that the package is compiled to arm64, but my r is for x86_64 architecture? How I can resolve it? I can't replace my x86-64 r with an arm64 r because it will completely mess up my existing working renv environment. I have no knowledge of how compiling works, is there a way to modify how the package is compiled?
I tried to download and install the arm64 binary from CRAN, same error. I then tried the x86_64 macos binary; R refuses to install it saying it is not a macos binary.

openssl depends on installed openssl libraries outside of R. Maybe this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65207249/resolving-openssl-install-error-in-rstudio helps.

Btw, I would first update the Operating system from 13.5 to 13.6.8. Then, why was R installed for darwin17.0? macOS 13 is on darwin22.x. Seems odd. I'd recommend a reinstall from scratch. Will be much more stable and straightforward this way.

@AndreWildberg I have openssl installed, multiple versions actually. One from brew and several versions from conda in my base environment. The installation defaults to the one from brew, but it gives a Projects/grnAnalysis/renv/staging/1/00LOCK-openssl/00new/openssl/libs/openssl.so, 0x0006): symbol not found in flat namespace '_PKCS12_SAFEBAG_free' error message. So I changed the installation configuration to the one from conda with R CMD INSTALL --configure-vars='INCLUDE_DIR=<include dir> LIB_DIR=<lib dir>' openssl_2.2.0.tar.gz. Then I got the error I posted.

@AndreWildberg Perhaps it was darwin 17 to be compatible with both x86_64 and arm64? I am not very familiar with macos at the system level. I will definitely try to reinstall r when I can. Or use conda r and r packages. It seems like a more convenient alternative.
